# how to call a specific folder with a partial path

Tags: c#, path, partial, filepath

I would like to get files info for this path "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\My Pictures" but without the need to write the whole path. I would like to have a partial path that contains the last folder only  which is my target folder:"My Pictures". I tried "c:\~\My Pictures" and some other combination but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: There is nothing in Windows that would do this.

Comment: Also, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "My Pictures");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx for the full enumeration of SpecialFolder

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
Path.Combine( Environment.GetFolderPath( SpecialFolder.MyDocuments ), "My Pictures" )
```